# SQL: How Do I Correctly Use Keyword 'BETWEEN' and Aggregate Function in IF, THEN, Else SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, aggregate

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @BeginDateQ1 date = '01-01-2010', @EndDateQ1 date = '12-31-2010'
BEGIN

SELECT 
   H.Type, H.SN, Sum(H.Hours), H.Date as 'Report Date', 
   H.OName, R.ReceivedDate, R.Confirmed, R.Part AS 'Part Number'
FROM 
   Hours H
INNER JOIN 
   Repair R ON H.SN = R.SN 
WHERE 
   (R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'O%' AND R.Confirmed NOT LIKE 'Y%')
   AND (H.Date BETWEEN @BeginDateQ1 AND @EndDateQ1) 
GROUP BY 
   H.Type, H.SN, H.Date, H.OName, R.ReceivedDate, R.Confirmed, R.Part 
ORDER BY 
   Date ASC
END
```

Which gives me my desired result.

I am having trouble with the following IF statement:

```
IF 
(SELECT R.ReceivedDate FROM Repair BETWEEN @BeginDate1 AND @EndDate1)
THEN
COUNT(R.Confirmed) 
END IF
```

ALSO, how would I properly include this IF statement in the original query that produced the original results I want?

NOTE that I need the count result from the IF statement to be used as a denominator for an equation and the numerator is the SUM(Hours) from line 3 of original query in the post.

This is a first time for me writing IF statements in SQL (only have done in C#).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `trouble with the following IF statement` - what is the trouble ?

Comment: My fault for not being concise.  I have squigglies.

Comment: If this is to be a denominator, how do you want to prevent division by 0 errors?

Comment: @DanBracuk Nice deduction.  if the denominator is 0 I am to use SUM(Hours) as the denominator giving my desired result 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF is a control flow statement, not to be used within a query.

```
IF (somecondition) THEN
  <sql statements>
ELSE
  <sql statements>
END
```

You can do that within a stored procedure. To do conditionals within a query, you need to use CASE...

```
SELECT col1, col2,
   CASE when col1='x' then 'HIT' else 'MISS' END
from myTable
```

which would give you a result with three columns, in the last column you would have the text 'HIT' or 'MISS' based on the value in col1.

Comment: would I use the CASE statement where I have my column paramateres?  IE.  Select A,B,C, CASE.....From......

Comment: Thanks, I chose your answer as the answer.  It was the easiest to perceive and the most easiest on the eyes in my query.

Comment: I suspected CASE was what you needed.

Comment: Oh also... please contact me at one of the contacts listed on my profile, I have a specific question that might help you but it's not something I can publicly ask about. I recognize this code...

Comment: I'm trying to locate your contact info but only see the blogspot link.

Comment: sorry I thought my email was available, it's part of my profile. Jasmine25011 on Google.

Answer (score 2):

A case construct might be what you are after.  Something like this.

```
, case when R.ReceivedDate  BETWEEN @BeginDate1 AND @EndDate1
then count(r.confirmed) else sum(0) end confirmations
```

**Edit Starts Here**

Note that this answer only shows the general idea.  Since the OP mentioned later that the result is to be a denominator, the alias has to go away.  Also, sum(0) has to be replaced by something representing sum(hours), whatever that might be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if the query returns any rows, use EXISTS()

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT R.ReceivedDate FROM Repair BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate)
BEGIN
 ... 
END
```

Comment: This is not even valid SQL.

Comment: @GSerg is it MY script that is not valid SQL?